# Connect wifi hotspot phone error: ENETUNREACH

Tags: java, android, android-wifi

I have an app, the app connect two phone using hotspot to send/recv file. One phone create hotspot (Wifi hotspot ), I  connect another hotspot phone using below code:

```
            mSocket = new Socket();

            try {

                mSocket.setReuseAddress(true);
                mSocket.bind(null);
                mSocket.setPerformancePreferences(0, 1, 2);
                mSocket.setTcpNoDelay(true);
                mSocket.setSoLinger(true, 0);
                mSocket.setKeepAlive(true);

                mSocket.connect(new InetSocketAddress(mConnection.getServerAddress(),
                        mConnection.getServerPort()), SOCKET_CONNECT_TIMEOUT);

           //operation here....
            } catch (SocketException e) {
                ((HotSpotConnection)mConnection).getlocalip();
                LogUtils.LOGE(LOG_TAG, "init exception:" + e.toString());
            } catch (IOException e) {
                LogUtils.LOGE(LOG_TAG, "init exception:" + e.toString());
            }
```

and I got the below error:

```
E/MyTestWifiThread(18918): init exception:java.net.ConnectException: 
failed to connect to /192.168.43.1 (port 9876) after 30000ms: 
isConnected failed: ENETUNREACH (Network is unreachable)
```

Why can't connect to hotspot phone, I am sure the hotspot phone address default 192.168.43.1? because I have pinged 192.168.43.1 and the hotspot phone replied.

Comment: I got the problem the same today. any recommandation debug methods for this question?

Answer (score 0):

I've encountered this problem before. and this works for me.

Change the way of communication for sockets.

Try open server socket on client which connects to hotspot, and create client socket on tethering device to connect to server socket.

[Android connect to tethering socket](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17839321/android-connect-to-tethering-socket)

this might help!!