# Cannot create socket connection to Android device running hotspot

Tags: android, sockets, hotspot

I have an Android phone running a hotspot and an app with a server socket running on port 10000.
The phones IP address is 192.168.43.1.

Another phone connects to the hotspot (address is 192.168.43.6) and tries to establish a socket to the other phone running the hotspot.

But that socket creation fails with a connection timeout.

Ping works in both directions and it works when both phone are connected to a regular WiFi router.

Is there some extra work required to get this scenario working on Android?

Comment: Is this really a programming question?

Comment: yes, because code needs to be fixed/extended. I do not expect it to be solved by a setting in Android.

Comment: What code? You haven't posted any.

Comment: I could post some standard code creating a socket and establishing a connection. But that would not add much value. I see that the question can also be a networking or android related one. But I think I will be pointed to programming when I start talking about sockets...

Answer (score 1):

It looks like this is not possible: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17928091/2445758

You cannot open a connection to the phone acting as a hotspot from a client.